# How to find system>administration>OS-uninstaller menu in Gnome?

Tags: gnome

I'd like to uninstall Windows 7, I read that through Gnome I can open an OS uninstaller, but I can't find the way... Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Its not a program that is included in Ubuntu, you will need to add it but first you must add the repository that includes it.  It is not in the standard sources, so you will not be able to find it in the Software Center either.  While not an official Ubuntu program I have used it and it worked flawlessly.

To install it type the following in the terminal to add the PPA(personal package archive)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

Then to get the package info on the PPA type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to install type

```
sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller
```

the -y in the above command will automatically answer yes to any questions, this is a dangerous thing to do in most cases but fot this program it is fine.

to start the program you can look in the menu but as the terminal is already open you can just type

```
os-uninstaller
```

You can also do the last 3 step at once by entering

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
```

you can then use the program to uninstall Windows.

For more in depth info please see the Ubuntu Help page that was also my [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was a bit tricky with my under-basic knowledge, but it seemed to work. Asked to remove the windows7, it did, but after the restart, the computer did not started, said the boot manager is missing... Now I'm clueless... I tried the Ubuntu live installer disc too, but no success.... Any idea?

Comment: do you mean that the live disk would not boot?  I've never heard of that happening even if your mbr is completely gone. or can you boot into the live disk?  if so you can repair the mbr with [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) you will use the 2nd option to install and run boot repair.  Boot Repair will only be installed in the live session not to your hard disk so it will be gone when you reboot but the repairs will be on your hard disk

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally tried this (as I dual boot), but you can download an uninstaller program. You can look here for information on how to install and use it (see the "second option"): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller. An alternative is to use a tool like GParted to format and delete the unwanted windows partition. Be sure to back up your files!

Comment: First, it is better to include instructions rather than just include a link.  More importantly, the last part of your answer WILL RESULT IN AN UNBOOTABLE SYSTEM.  If you just delete the partition then the bootloader (grub) will error when it cannot find the Windows partition.  It is also not recommended to use Gparted on a booted system, it should be done from the liveDVD to avoid damaging the partitions or the partition table.